# Tree view showing extra empty fields

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have created a custom module, in my tree view, I will always have only 1 row data. But in my tree view it shows extra empty rows. how can I remove those unwanted empty rows?

[image: See the image for reference]

My view code:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="ctimesheet.list">
    <field name="name">ctimesheet list</field>
    <field name="model">time.recorder</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="TIME SHEET" create="false">
        <field name="total_time"/>
        <field name="month_time"/>
        <field name="yesterday_time"/>
        <field name="week_time"/>
        <field name="notsubmitted_time"/>
        <field name="user_id" invisible="1"/>
    </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

updating javascript by editing odoo code is very bad you shoud use include to override
the code:

Create a new module  and create a javascript file:

```
    /your_addon_name/static/src/js/list_view.js
```

in you javascript file override the render method like this:

```
    odoo.define('you_module_name.ListView', function (require) {
           "use strict";

           // First retrieve the veiw from view_registry
           ListView = core.view_registry.get('list');

           // now use include to override the render method
           ListView.include({
                render: function () {
                    // call super method first
                    this._super();
                    // then override what you need
                    // and best thing here is that you can dor this for
                    // your model only
                    if (this.model == 'addon_name.model_name'){
                        this.pad_table_to(1);
                    }
                }
           });

        }
```

of curse just writing javascript will not do the trick we should put ower java script file to backends_asset template
to be loaded in odoo backend.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend_custom_id" name="list_view assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_addon_name/static/src/js/list_view.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

don't forget to put the xml file to odoo manifest hope this helps you and everyone else

Comment: I was not able to make this snipped work on Odoo 9, was it working for you ?

Comment: @ATX yes it does.

Comment: @Charif DZ this should be the accepted answer, The accepted one it shuold never be followed

Answer (score 6):

just go to path: Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\static\src\js\views and edit file **list_view.js** **line 1115**
and change

```
this.pad_table_to(4);
```

To

```
this.pad_table_to(1);
```