# How to add more default empty rows in list view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I need to add more default empty rows in the list view.

[image: reference image]

Right now, it only gives 4 empty rows on a new record. However, I need to add, say, 10 more default empty rows.

This is because I increased the height of the table using css.

```
.o_list_view .o_list_table {
    height: 800px;
}
```

The result is that it still has 4 rows on default but every row has their height as 25% of the table height. Therefore, I need to add some rows into it so that their height will be fit to the new table height again.

Or another solution, if possible, remove the auto height adjustment for the rows in the table so that it won't be scaled according to the table height.

Either solution is acceptable.

Comment: Try giving this.pad_table_to(10); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468472/tree-view-showing-extra-empty-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the length of the lines is less than `4`, Odoo will try to add an empty row.

To add more default empty rows, you can alter `ListRenderer` [_renderBody](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L471):

```
_renderBody: function () {
    var self = this;
    var $rows = this._renderRows();
    while ($rows.length < 14) {
        $rows.push(self._renderEmptyRow());
    }
    return $('<tbody>').append($rows);
},
```

You can also set a `empty_rows` attribute in the `tree` tag to define the number of empty rows:

***XML***:

```
<tree string="" editable="bottom" empty_rows="4">
```

***JavaScript***:

```
var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');

ListRenderer.include({
    _renderBody: function () {
        var self = this;
        var empty_rows = 4;
        if (self.arch && self.arch.attrs.empty_rows) {
            empty_rows = self.arch.attrs.empty_rows;
        }
        var $rows = this._renderRows();
        while ($rows.length < empty_rows) {
            $rows.push(this._renderEmptyRow());
        }
        return $('<tbody>').append($rows);
    },
});
```

Check [Assets Management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) on how to add the above code to `web.assets_backend` bundle and [Javascript Module System](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#javascript-module-system) to create a JavaScript module